# Android show the datepicker(end date) greater than the start date?

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-datepicker

Hello guys i want to show the date  picker(end date) after the date select from the start date.The end date picker will display date after the from date.End date will  display date picker after the from date and before from date will not gonna show .what i got to do?
What i am trying is

```
       fromdate = (EditText) findViewById(fromDate);
       todate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todate);
       fromdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
    todate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showToDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
    }
public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
   }
 public void showToDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ToDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        fromdate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
           }   }

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
       DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        view.setMinDate(fromDate);
        todate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year); } }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically go from one date picker to the next. I am confused at what you are attempting to ask, can you clarify please

Comment: use [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and setMinDate(long) and setMaxDate(long)

or You can use [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) passing start data and (OnDateSetListener)[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html]

Comment: @Sam I have Two edit text boxes.one is start date and end date.When i click each edit text box like start date ,datepicker is opened to choose a date.now my question end date (datepicker) will show the dates after the from date.

Comment: Oh so you want to update the date picker on the end Date to be the first date after the selected from date correct? If so, just share the selected date on close to class variable of fromDate and pass to toDate on startup as the date to use instead of getting current date, use the toDate and add 1 day to it

Comment: I'll post as answer for you to elaborate on if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     fromdate = (EditText) findViewById(fromDate);
    todate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todate);
    fromdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showTruitonDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
    todate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showToDatePickerDialog(view);
        }
    });
}
public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showToDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ToDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, year, 
        month,day);
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        fromdate.setText(day + "/" + month  + "/" + year);
    }

}

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
   // Calendar startDateCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
          String getfromdate = fromdate.getText().toString().trim();
          String getfrom[] = getfromdate.split("/");
        int year,month,day;
             year= Integer.parseInt(getfrom[2]);
             month = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[1]);
            day = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[0]);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year,month,day+1);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, year,month,day);
       datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        todate.setText(day + "/" + month  + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

I choose a start date as....1/09/2017
   [image]
Then i open a end date it displays from....2/09/2017
 [image]

Comment: but the month shows minus one(For JULY to returns 06)!!?

Answer (score 2):

try to use this code

```
    public static boolean isDateAfter(String startDate,String endDate)
    {
    try
    {
        String myFormatString = "yyyy-M-dd"; // for example
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
        Date date1 = df.parse(endDate));
        Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

        if (date1.after(startingDate))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        return false;
    }
}
```

It return true if enddate is after start date.

Answer (score 1):

Define startDateCalendar like

```
Calendar startDateCalendar=Callendar.getInstance();
```

And update fragments code

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity,this, year, month,day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return datePickerDialog;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user

            fromdate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
            startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            startDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        }   }

    public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return datePickerDialog;
        }
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            view.setMinDate(fromDate);
            todate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year); } }
```

Comment: it works but whats the problem is End date picker will work with respect to  current date.i want to work with respect to from date

Comment: @karthi you are taking year,month and day from calendar instance due to that is shown current date calendar instance returns current date

Comment: @J Ramesh if i choose start date 05/11/2016...then end date will display    next day from start date.like date picker will show date from 06/11/2016.i don't need any limitation in start date.

Comment: @karthi then remove datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); this line

Comment: @karthi Are you want to select start date before current date? then remove setMinDate() it's working my side

Comment: yes bro it's working.But no need of current date in both start date and end date.actually limit the end date with respect to start date.

Comment: then datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(startDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis()); this line will limit end date for selecting end date after start date and also show dialog with start date as default date

Comment: bro i added your line but end date will show date from current date that means 4/10/2017.But i choose start date as 1/09/2017.Actually end date will show from 2/09/2017.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155898/discussion-between-karthi-and-j-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

you can use setMinDate and setMaxDate methods to the datepickerdialog.

eg:
     DatePicker toPicker = Util.getDatePicker(getActivity(), toDateSetListener, toYear, toMonth, toDay)
                        .getDatePicker();
                toPicker.setMinDate(getToMinDate());
                toPicker.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

Answer (score 0):

So when you close your fromDate Dialog just store the variables in class level.

fromYear
fromMonth
fromDay

then when you launch toDate(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay) to the dialog
then instead of calendar. get current dates, just use the from and add +1 to the day for starting the picker at the next day. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There is library called MaterialDateRangePicker which exactly solves your problem
Please find the link 
https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker