# set mindate of second datepicker from selected date from first datepicker android studio

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm creating booking reservation and my module first are date picker (Check-in and Check-out). I'm trying all codes that can help me from my *date picker*. But nothing happens. I would like to set the `mindate` of my second *date picker* from the selected date of my first *date picker*.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you.

Example:

> current date = January 01, 2018
>   check - in date=  January 24, 2018
>   Check -out mindate should be supposed to be January 25 up to higher (can choose)

```
 /** DATE PICKER DIALOG _ START **/

    etin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckin);
    etin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    etout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcheckout);
    etout.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    //initialization
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd  yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //set ng current date
    String departureDatetime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    etin.setText(departureDatetime);

    // Determine min date to select in calendar.
    mMinReturnDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    //set ng current date plus 1 day para sa check out
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String returnDatetime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    etout.setText(returnDatetime);

    etin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            // Show the date picker dialog fragment
            dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker Check In");
            //end


        }
    });

    etout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            DatePickerFragmentCheckOut dFragmentOut = new DatePickerFragmentCheckOut();
            // Show the date picker dialog fragment
            dFragmentOut.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker Check Out");
            //end
        }
    });
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);

        c.set(2018, 11, 31);//Year,Month -1,Day
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        return dpd;

    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the chosen date
        EditText etin = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etcheckin);

        // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);

        etin.setText(formattedDate);
    }
}

public static class DatePickerFragmentCheckOut extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + 1);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        DatePickerDialog dpdOut = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert, this, year, month, day);


        c.set(2018, 11, 31);//Year,Month -1,Day
        dpdOut.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

        Date min = new Date();

        dpdOut.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        return dpdOut;

    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the chosen date
        EditText etout = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.etcheckout);

        // Create a Date variable/object with user chosen date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date chosenDate = cal.getTime();

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(chosenDate);

        etout.setText(formattedDate);
    }

}


/** DATE PICKER DIALOG _ END **/`
```

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: I fiound this [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557387/android-show-the-datepickerend-date-greater-than-the-start-date) as useful guide for my datepicker but it contains errors for  

  fromdate.setText(day + "/" + month  + "/" + year);
String getfromdate = fromdate.getText().toString().trim();
 todate.setText(day + "/" + month  + "/" + year);

 for example, the error said nonstatic field  "fromdate" cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: set selected date from first dialog in a `Calender` instance and use that in 2nd one to set `minDate`.